# Save Post Permalink In .txt File

Tags: plugins, functions

Please I want to achieve a Goal of Saving Post Permalink In a .txt file.

Example: if any post is publish from a specify category, it will save the post permalink structure /%postname%/ (without the sitename). in a .txt file in my file manager root folder.

Each link structure should be in a new line of the .txt file.

Please Gurus Is there anyway this can be done using theme function or something similar.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do it this way? There's easier ways to get all the urls of your posts without saving them to a text file.

Comment: I wanted it in a text file, so that I can use it as xml sitemap. Using php code, but in the other way round how can I get the post permalink from specific category into a .XML file. I want to use it to create sitemap of another site.

Comment: There's many many XML sitemap plugins available. Have you tried any?

Comment: Yes, I am using my wp category as subdomain (on One WP Install).using [Main Category as Subdomain Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/main-category-as-subdomain/). so the subdomain does not have a sitemap on its own. So I am looking for techniques to create sitemap for those category. because Google xml sitemap plugins does not support subdomains  url in root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got enough points to comment a link and I don't wish to plagiarise the answer from another website, but I hope this helps

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'update_txt_file' );
add_action( 'publish_page', 'update_txt_file' );
```

Reference: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-update-a-file-after-new-post-or-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, its a bit close, but Is there any way record the permalink from a specific category ?

Comment: via the Link Provided, It create duplicated permalink url for specific post. And i would love it more if it is from a specific category.

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda, you could wrap the inside of the function with an if-statement, stating: `if ( is_category( 'example' ) : //do fwrite stuff endif;`

Could you also just record the category beside the link?
`$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id ) . ' / ' . get_category( $post_id ) . "\r\n";`

Comment: Also possibly see https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-automatically-create-sitemap-xml-without-plugin/

Comment: The Sitemap code does not work on theme function.php redirects to error page. it is not working. I have tried it on many of my sites no way out.

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda again, the third comment is the solution to save `if( is_category('X') )`.